# keeping a div value after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

There are total 8 textboxes in my html form.I am displaying 2 of the textboxes by default and 6 are set to `display:none`.All these textboxes are wrapped with `divs` (named `fa1` to `fa8`). I have added a button which will display the hidden divs(named from `fa3` to `fa8`) upon each click.

html code:

```
<input  type="hidden" id="countfa" name="countfa" value="3" readonly>
<button type="button" onClick="AddNewFa();" id="addfa" > + Add New FA </button>
```

I am using below javascript to listen the click and count and display hidden `divs`

```
function AddNewFa() 
    {
        var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),9) ;
        if( facount < 9)
            {
                facount = facount+1;

                for(i=3;i<9;i++)
                {
                    if( i<facount )
                        $('#fa'+i).slideDown("fast");
                    else
                        $('#fa'+i).slideUp("fast"); 

                }
                $('#countfa').val(facount);  

            }
             }
```

The problem that I am facing here is after form submit `countfa` value changing back to its default value 3. So if I have showing all hidden div before form submit after clicking the button `countfa` value will be 8, and after form submit it will be 3 again. Is there anyway I can keep `countfa` value as 8 ? even after form submit ?

Comment: You can store the values in a database using PHP and retrieve it each visit to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if i understood you correctly, but i faced a similar problem in the past and i resolved it rather easily. You can simply retrieve the value of countfa and then set its value.

Since you are using php, you can simply use this code

Note: Im assuming your using POST, if you are using GET then simply replace `$_POST` with `$_GET`

When you get to the part of your code printing the countfa div, simply use this code (Im assuming your using html and will introduce the php inline. Else just remove the `<?php ?>` tags

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['countfa'])){
     echo "<input  type=\"hidden\" id=\"countfa\" name=\"countfa\" value=\"$_POST['countfa']\" readonly>";
    }else{
     echo "<input  type=\"hidden\" id=\"countfa\" name=\"countfa\" value=\"3\" readonly>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: It giving me below parse error `syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING` at `echo "<input  type=\"hidden\" id=\"countfa\" name=\"countfa\" value=\"$_POST['facount']\" readonly>";`

Comment: I made a small typing mistake. Its fixed. You can copy the code again. (I mistakenly typed countfa as facount, sorry D: )

Comment: Getting same error. I just tried to change code like `      <?php
 if(isset($_POST['countfa'])){ 
 $valueid = $_POST['countfa'];
echo $valueid;
echo '<input  type="hidden" id="countfa" name="countfa" value="$valueid" readonly>';
 }else{
echo '<input  type="hidden" id="countfa" name="countfa" value="3" readonly>'; 
 }
?>` this not giving any parse but i see `value="$valueid"` not taking value

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in the [browser local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) and check after page load if a previous value is stored and restore it if that's the case.

Here is the minimal working example: http://jsfiddle.net/C5Fe7/

```
$(function () {
    if (localStorage['countfa']) {
        $('#countfa').val(localStorage['countfa']);
    }

    $('#addfa').click(AddNewFa);
    $('form').submit(function () {
       localStorage['countfa'] = $('#countfa').val();
    });
});
```